# Return Customer Number with highest number of order

Tags: mysql

Question,

You are given the table "**ORDERS**"

Return the customerNumber to the customer that has placed the highest number of order(it is guaranteed that there is only one customer with the most orders).

[image]

My guess was to return highest repeated customer number but couldn't get the exact syntax.

My Answer (Doesn't Work)

```
SELECT 'customerNumber' 

FROM 'ORDERS' 

GROUP BY 'customerNumber' 

ORDER BY COUNT(*) 

DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Your query is correct besides the quotes around the table and column names. Remove them or use backticks.

Comment: order by needs to be desc `order by count(*) desc`  as you want the highest count at the top since you limit by 1.

Comment: xQbert: It is... Look closely

Comment: @juergend wow... so use to seeing desc /asc on same line  as order by... I didn't even notice it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT customerNumber 

FROM ORDERS 

GROUP BY customerNumber 

ORDER BY COUNT(*) 

DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Write your MySQL query statement below

SELECT customer_number FROM orders
GROUP BY customer_number
ORDER BY count(order_number) DESC
LIMIT 1;

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your answer is basically the same as the existing and upvoted one. Please do not post answers that do not have anything substantial to add.